# Struts 2 server side validation using XML not working for struts action

Tags: struts2, validation, struts-validation

I am using Struts 2 Validator framework with XML. But the server side validations are not working. Following is the code snippet.

**Struts.xml**

```
<interceptor-stack name="MyStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="profiling"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,.*\\.*,.*\(.*,.*\).*,.*@.*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,reset</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,reset</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>

<action name="process" method="process" class="org.web.action.MyAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="MyStack" />
    <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    <result name="wait">wait.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">Index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**MyAction.java**

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String amount;
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String process() throws Exception {
       //some processing done here    
    }
}
```

**MyAction-process-validation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
        "@@xwork.validator.dtd@@">
<validators>
    <field name="amount">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true">
            <message key="order.amount.required"/>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="amountValidator" short-circuit="true">
            <message key="order.amount.invalid" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**AmountValidator.java**

```
public class AmountValidator extends FieldValidatorSupport {
    public Struts2DonationAmountValidator() {
        super();
    }

    public void validate(Object object) throws ValidationException {
        //some validation check here
    }
}
```

**validators.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
        "https://s3.amazonaws.com/static/xwork-validator-config-1.0.dtd">
<validators>
    <validator name="required" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.validators.RequiredFieldValidator" />
    <validator name="amountValidator" class="org.web.validator.AmountValidator"/>
</validators>
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<input type="text" id="amountTemp" name="amount">
```

I have put sysouts at the first line of validator as well as in action method. The sysout in **AmountValidator.java** is not called. Even while debugging, the validation doesn't get called and the control jumps to action method. There is no hint of any exception in console. The action method flow works fine.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, you define "required" and try to use "requiredstring". First see if you can get the default validators to work; you do not need to create entries for the default validators.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for prompt reply. I changed it to "requiredstring". But the default validator is not working as well. I could not find whether there is something related to configuration?

Comment: Create a minimally-failing example and put it on github somewhere and I'll take a look.

Comment: Fine, I will try to create a project and put it somewhere. But meanwhile let meknow if you want some more info from the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a other solution on http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/validation.html. I changed the name of my MyAction-process-validation.xml to MyAction-processAction-validation.xml and named my action as processAction instead of process. That means instead of method I used action name.

Thanks for your support.